# Animation by looping through objects

Tags: animation

I have a use case where I have a folder of .PLY files (say `0.ply` to `99.ply`) that together make up a certain action (e.g. throwing a ball) over 100 frames. I would like to be able to create an animation that is 100 frames long in which `t.ply` is visible at time step `t` and invisible for all other time steps.

Additionally, I would like to do some basic preprocessing (e.g. centering the geometry). As the preprocessing is equal for every .PLY file, I'm looking for a more automatic way to apply such a preprocessing to all of them at once.